# react multiple input field with same name attribute triggers multiple updates in different inputs

Tags: forms, reactjs, dictionary, input

So, the problem is below.

```
  handleBankAccountInput = (e, key) => {
let name = e.target.name;
let value = e.target.value;
let validation = e.target.key;
let bankAccounts = {...this.state.bankAccounts};
let ibanValid = bankAccounts[key].validationState.iban;
let banknameValid = bankAccounts[key].validationState.bankname;
bankAccounts[key][name] = value;

switch(validation) {
  case 'iban':
    ibanValid = IBAN.isValid(value); // true
    bankAccounts[key].fieldValidationErrors.iban = ibanValid ? '' : ' is invalid IBAN';
    bankAccounts[key].validationState.iban = ibanValid ? 'success' : 'error';
    console.log("why validate all iban of bankAccounts of key: " + key );
    console.log(bankAccounts[key]);

    break;
  case 'bankname':
    banknameValid = value.length >=1; // true
    bankAccounts[key].fieldValidationErrors.bankname = banknameValid ? '' : ' is invalid bankname';
    bankAccounts[key].validationState.bankname = banknameValid ? 'success' : 'error';
    console.log("why validate all bankname of bankAccounts of key: " + key );
    console.log(bankAccounts[key]);
    break;
  default:
    break;
}

// bankAccounts[key] = bankAccount;
this.setState({bankAccounts: bankAccounts}, this.validateForm);
bankAccounts = {};
}
```

Problem:

> The line  '    bankAccounts[key].fieldValidationErrors.iban =
>   ibanValid ? '' : ' is invalid IBAN'; ' is triggered by other inputs
>   with same name attribute.

```
  addBankAccountInput = () => {
let bankAccounts = {...this.state.bankAccounts};
// add in our new menu
let bankAccount = {...this.state.bankAccount};
bankAccount['iban'] = '';
bankAccount['bankname'] = '';
bankAccount['validationState']['iban'] = '';
bankAccount['validationState']['bankname'] = '';
bankAccount['formErrors']['iban'] = '';
bankAccount['formErrors']['bankname'] = '';
bankAccount['fieldValidationErrors']['iban'] = '';
bankAccount['fieldValidationErrors']['bankname'] = '';

let accountnum = 0;
if(bankAccounts) {
  Object.keys(bankAccounts).map((key) => accountnum++ );
}

bankAccounts[accountnum] = bankAccount;
this.setState({ bankAccounts: bankAccounts });
bankAccount = {};
bankAccounts = {};
}
```

This is how I add empty bankAccount inputs.

```
  renderBankAccountInput = (key) => {
return (
  <div key={key}>
    <FormGroup controlId={'formHorizontalBankAccount'+key} validationState={this.state.bankAccounts[key].validationState.iban}>
      <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
        IBAN
      </Col>
      <Col sm={10}>
        <FormControl type="text" name={'iban'+key} key='iban' value={this.state.bankAccounts[key].iban} placeholder="iban" onChange={(e) => this.handleBankAccountInput(e, key)} />
      </Col>
      <FormControl.Feedback />
      <HelpBlock>{this.state.bankAccounts[key].formErrors.iban}</HelpBlock>
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup controlId={'formHorizontalBankAccount' + key} validationState={this.state.bankAccounts[key].validationState.bankname}>
      <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
        Bankname
      </Col>
      <Col sm={10}>
        <FormControl type="text" name={'bankname'+key} key='bankname' value={this.state.bankAccounts[key].bankname} placeholder="Bank name" onChange={(e) => this.handleBankAccountInput(e, key)} />
      </Col>
      <FormControl.Feedback />
      <HelpBlock>{this.state.bankAccounts[key].formErrors.bankname}</HelpBlock>
    </FormGroup>
  </div>
)
}
```

This is how I render inputs.

Like this.

### Bank accounts

```
    {Object.keys(this.state.bankAccounts).map(this.renderBankAccountInput)}
    { this.state.bankAccounts.length < 1 &&
      <HelpBlock>You should provide at least one bank account</HelpBlock>
    }
    <button
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.addBankAccountInput();
      }}
    >Add Bank Account</button>`
```

Would appreciate your help!

Comment: This is a gist link for the entire code. [link](https://gist.github.com/Seunghunsh/1276e010def94ac1863e729d2f88c9ba)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to a tricky and headache problem of React. You are using the array index as the `key` to mapped components by this line `<div key={key}>`. It makes React confused when updating the array, to which property belong to which component and leads to an unpredictable result.

You can refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773892/wrong-components-rendered-by-preact) with more explanation about the issue in [Preact](https://preactjs.com/), which is an alternative to React. The explanation can also be applied in React as well.

Solution:

- Generate an uuid to your component list. There are my library provides this feature like [lodash-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-uuid) or [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid)
- In your situation, you can use `bankAccounts[key][iban]` as your component key.

Comment: Hey Firice, appreciate it. However, now input fields are not showing up which I don't understand.

Comment: Can you check if there is any error show up in console ?